How is this question not suitable for this site?
The question: Does asking counterfactual questions about the context/conditions of one's birth presuppose the existence of souls?

How is it not suitable for this site?
(Interestingly, some of the close voters also wrote answers to the question, which seems inconsistent.)

Agreed. Seems a legitimate question, and I don't think it's pushing a personal philosophy because the question doesn't appear biased towards either possible answer. It invites a hard look at the nature of counterfactual conditionals. 4 votes and tag me, I'll be 5th.

It's not strictly inconsistent to answer and vote to close, in many cases. A question about cooking cashew chicken may be off topic here, but one may still post a recipe as an answer while agreeing it should be closed.

I am not one of the downvoters, but I am not keen on the question. It is very similar to the questions linked. The only difference seems to be the reference to a soul.
Also, to be blunt, the answers are of low quality. They are not attempting to provide expert answers in accordance with the aims of StackExchange. If anything, it is the answers rather than the question that are attempting to push personal philosophy. Maybe some of the downvoters voted for that reason.
The answers to the linked question Why am I this particular human being? are somewhat better. A good answer should address the issues of personal identity and counterfactual reasoning. It should describe some of the main positions that have been defended by prominent philosophers and ideally reference some of them, such as Thomas Nagel, David Chalmers, Saul Kripke, David Lewis and Derek Parfitt. Ideally, it should show how the question is related to traditional issues in the philosophy of mind such as the persistence of identity and the relation between mind and body.
For those reasons, although I am usually quite happy to vote to reopen questions, I won't be this time.

Human beings are a rather irrational bunch sometimes, and I would consider if some contributors might have user80226 fatigue. My sense of it is that most users operate on an intuitional basis, and questions that are marginally acceptable questions can be closed based on aspects such as topic, implied worldview, and author. Arguably some viewers might view your curiosity as flooding the board, especially as Bumble has said, if your questions resemble each other. My view is any question that meets my personal criteria should be defended and kept open, but many users have more stringent standards or a less generous interpretation as what counts as philosophy.
Given the statistics recently presented, I would angle that the charity some users might apply to a new user might have been spent in your case. I even saw some speculation you were soliciting answers for some ML purpose. Anytime a question is closed, it's certainly an opportunity to reflect on writing questions in general.

Agree with both key points here (a) I (and evidently you) are not fed up with @user80226, but others are (b) So while I don't want/need rate limits in this case, I'm fine supporting those that do. (c) I deleted my answer cautioning against the efficacy of blanket rate limits because evidently ppl dont agree. As of now OP gets my reopen vote because we have no consensus on how to move ahead, just ad hoc thrashing actions. That said I find this a more than usually splendid question for highlighting the confused inconsistency of strong physicalists and suspect the closure comes from beingcornered


Does asking counterfactual questions about the context/conditions of one's birth presuppose the existence of souls?

This looks like the "What if" fallacy.
All this leads to unfalsifiable speculation. I didn't VTC or downvote, but imho this is just a seed for opinions and discussion.

For myself, I'm not sure there really is such a thing as the what-if fallacy. What the linked page is describing is the error of claiming that some statement is true when it is only a speculation and is not supported by evidence. That doesn't have anything essentially to do with counterfactuals. Websites like to create huge lists of so-called fallacies, but the reality is that many of these are spurious, and logic has little to do with fallacies anyway.
